# Application variables in service

Tags: android, service, process

I create the app with a foreground service. The service runing in another process and thread.

The Application class have an Array and have public method getArray. Service can access to Application and call method getArray.

App started, array fill and service started. 
If app change the array, service return the array created at start app.

How i can update the array in the service?

on service:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if(mThread != null)
        mThread.interrupt();
    mApplication = (Application) getApplication();
    mTaskManager = mApplication.getTaskManager();

    TaskArray lTasks = mTaskManager.getAll();

    // always return same size
    Log.d(mLogTag, "onStartCommand " + lTasks.size());

    createThread();

    mThread.start();
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

**RESULT:**

I was found the reason of getting a copy of applicaton object in my app. This is happening because getApplicationContext() return the context of the single, global Application object of the **current process**.

For each process created a copy of application object.

Comment: So your question is how you can update arraylist values from service?

Comment: You can have two way communication between client app and remote service using Messenger

Comment: Piyush Kukadiya, what does you mean about Messenger?

Answer (score 1):

Get the context of Application class by using getApplicatonContext() in your service class by writing this line **((YourApplicatonClassName)getApplicationContext()).getArray()** and set the new data value .
It is better, if possible, to share your code so that I can understand what you exactly want. 
Thanks

Comment: I'm doing this, but method getArray return me the old array. As if when service started, it create a copy of application class.

Comment: Then I think you should make setArrayValue() method, a setter, and set new values to it after clearing Array with old values.

Comment: Thanks, i will try this, but i want to understand why it create a copy, and how it works inside.